# Netsuite - how to send a sublist value?

Tags: php, netsuite

I'm having a really hard time to send a sublist value on Netsuite, could someone give me a hint?

my code looks like this:

```
 $customer->address = "City B";
 $customer->phone = "111-111";
 $customer->officePhone = "333-333";
```

and I am not sure how I should sent a sublist value, should it be like this?

```
 $customer->address->array('city' = "address field");
```

I've tried to search this simple question but I couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the PHP version of the code updating a customer address in Netsuite.

```
/**
* Updates Customer AddressBook in Netsuite
*
* @param int $iInternalId
* @param array $aAddress
* @return boolean
*/
function setAddressbook( $iInternalId, array $aAddress ){

$service = new NetSuiteService();
$address = new CustomerAddressBook();
$address->defaultShipping = false;
$address->defaultBilling = false;
$address->attention = $aAddress['attention'];
$address->addressee = $aAddress['addressee'];
$address->addr1 = $aAddress['addr1'];
$address->addr2 = $aAddress['addr2'];
$address->addr3 = $aAddress['addr3'];
$address->city = $aAddress['city'];
$address->state = $aAddress['state'];
$address->zip = $aAddress['zip'];

$addressBook = new CustomerAddressbookList();
$addressBook->addressbook = array($address);
// In case you want to Update and NOT Replace
$addressBook->replaceAll = false;

$customer = new Customer();
$customer->addressbookList = $addressBook;
$customer->internalId = $iInternalId;

$request = new UpdateRequest();
$request->record = $customer;

$updateResponse = $service->update($request);

if (!$updateResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
return( false );
}
return( true );
}
```

Comment: thanks @rockstar it sorta worked but I guess now the problem is with the netsuite form.